# How to Translate Vue i18n of v-for data Array of String

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am new to vuejs and doing my project with multi language feature, German and English, but I have problem with data Array of String which is loops through of a lists, and I don't know how to translate it, here's what I meant

```js
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          text: "Explore Components",
          name: "vuetifyjs vuetify-loader",
        },
        {
          text: "Select a layout",
          name: "vuetifyjs vuetify",
        },
        {
          text: "Frequently Asked Questions",
          name: "vuetifyjs awesome-vuetify",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

I want to translate the **items.text** in German and English, and here's my de.json and en.json

```json
// de.json
{
  "whatsNext": {
    "components": "Komponenten erforschen",
    "selectLayout": "Layout wählen",
    "frequentQuestion": "Häufig gestellte Fragen"
  }
}

// en.json
{
"whatsNext": {
    "components": "Explore components",
    "selectLayout": "Select a layout",
    "frequentQuestion": "Frequently Asked Questions"
  }
}
```

normally you can just `{{ $t('whatsNext.components') }}`  but since it loops in v-for I don't know how, can someone help?

I tried this but it doesn't work and only renders german, since the locale in German

```json
data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          text: this.$root.$t("whatsNext.components"),
          name: "vuetifyjs vuetify-loader",
        },
        {
          text: this.$root.$t("whatsNext.selectLayout"),
          name: "vuetifyjs vuetify",
        },
        {
          text: this.$root.$t("whatsNext.frequentQuestion"),
          name: "vuetifyjs awesome-vuetify",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Comment: So you're not asking to have the site support multiple languages and render in whatever language the user picks. You're asking to have multiple languages displayed on a page at the same time?

Comment: No No, I'm asking only renders in whatever language the user picks @bassxzero

Comment: `I tried this but it doesn't work and only renders german, since the locale in German` Did you try setting the locale to english? Most i18n packages try to detect the locale currently being used in the browser and will render using that.

Comment: I did tried : `
  locale: "de",
  fallbackLocale: "en"` or en and en or en and de, but it only renders one language @bassxzero

Comment: If you are using google chrome for testing your app, then download this extension. It will let you easily switch the locale you are using so you can test both versions of the site. I'm sure other browsers have a similar extension/plugin.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: I'd not translate the texts in `data()` but instead only include the translation keys there… (this way you can reactively change the language)

Comment: translation keys how ? @slauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not translate the texts in `data()` but instead only include the static translation keys there:

```javascript
data() {
  return {
    items: [
      {
        text_key: "whatsNext.components",
        name: "vuetifyjs vuetify-loader",
      },
      {
        text_key: "whatsNext.selectLayout",
        name: "vuetifyjs vuetify",
      },
      {
        text_key: "whatsNext.frequentQuestion",
        name: "vuetifyjs awesome-vuetify",
      },
    ],
  };
},
```

And then, in your template:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.text_key">
    {{ $t(item.text_key) }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

With v9.x you can get access to the array by using $tm('YOUR FIELD')

As documented here: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#tm-key and discussed here: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/91#issuecomment-1070794621

You need to use rt for the locale message returned by tm

```
<div class="container">
  <template v-for="content in tm('contents')">
    <h2>{{ rt(content.title) }}</h2>
    <p v-for="paragraph in content.paragraphs">
        {{ rt(paragraph) }}
    </p>
  </template>
</div>
```